# richfaces 4 and prototype

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, prototypejs, richfaces

I have an application that uses richfaces 4.1 components and relies on an old, self-written library that uses prototype. Now, when I use both on the same page I get conflicts on the $ function, which is called by richfaces a few times.

Is there any way to force richfaces into a non-conflict version of jQuery? Or is this already the case by default and something else is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem the original poster has is his code is calling Prototype, **not** jQuery, but RichFaces 4.1 has dropped Prototype and now assumes $ is always pointing to jQuery.  So if one uses noConflict(), the RichFaces generated Javascript fails because it emits code like `$('#id_1')` and $ is not pointing jQuery.  And there is no way to wrap the RichFaces js.

Turns out this is a known bug: [RF-11881](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11881).  It should be fixed in RichFaces 4.3.0 Milestone 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.noConflict() and then each time you write javascript code wrap it in anonymous function like this

```
(function($){

// here $ is jQuery object!


})(jQuery);
```